# How to compress project size in codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I want to compress(shrink) project size. I want to know that where should I add this attribute "Compress=true" in build.xml. Can you provide some sample code for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <jar compress="true" jarfile="${dist.jar}" includes="**/*" basedir="build/tmp" >
        <exclude name="**/package-info.class" />
        <exclude name="**/Thumbs.db" />
    </jar>
```